# Convert String to the name of a array in another class

Tags: java, arrays, string, class, int

I'm a amateur programmer and I'm wondering if it's possible to solve a problem in a specific way.

```
public class Stats {

public static int[] Hero = {20, 20, 10, 10, 10};
public static int[] Villain = {20, 20, 10, 10, 10};

public static void name(int[] name) {
    //If you insert an array it will print all its values
    System.out.println("Health: " + name[1] + "/" + name[0]);
    System.out.println("Damage: " + name[2]);
    System.out.println("Defense: " + name[3]);
    System.out.println("Agility: " + name[4]);
    return;
}
```

This is what I want to use and if I call on it using 'Hero' or 'Villain' it works fine.

```
    public class UserInterface extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    //A lot of code in between that is not of notice right now

    @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (" ".equals(CHESS.Board[e.getY() / squareSize][e.getX() / squareSize]) == false) {
                //Checks if I pressed on a legit space on the map

                String name = (CHESS.Board[e.getY() / squareSize][e.getX() / squareSize]);
                //In this scenario 'name' will be a String called "Hero"

                System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                //Will write out 'Name: Hero'

                Stats.name(Stats.Hero);
                //Works fine

                Stats.name(Stats.name);
                //Does not work

            }
        }
```

Now what I want is to call on the right array depending on what i clicked. For the moment I only have arrays called 'Hero' and 'Villain' but in the end there will surly be over 50+ arrays to choose from on a map. Obviously just writing stats.name(Stats.name); does not work cause name is a String and it wants a int[].

But is there a way to to use my string 'name' in such a way that i can call on an int[] array named the same thing in a different class?

Comment: Java is an object oriented language, an as such, it really does benefit you to take advantage of the features present in the language you've chosen. You should be creating a Person object with common fields used by both Hero and Villain subclasses. One of the fields in Person is going to be name. Other fields will correspond to the various stats. There are better ways to get where you need to go.

Comment: maybe this questions belongs in better in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is look up an object by name.  You can't do it literally the way you have, but it's common and you don't have to add to much code.

Let's say you have an RPG game and you have team members, which each little computer person identified by name.

```
Map<String,RpgPerson> team = new HashMap<>();
```

Here we have a way to map a string (the name) to the object we want (the one with all the stats).  I'm using the suggestion above to make a "Person" object because it really is better than using an array.

Here's a quick example:

```
public class RpgPersonExample
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Map<String, RpgPerson> team = new HashMap<>();
      team.put( "Sgt. Mayhem", new RpgPerson( 100, 10, 0 ) );
      team.put( "Wizard", new RpgPerson( 100, 1, 10 ) );
      team.put( "Dragon", new RpgPerson( 1000, 100, 100 ) );

      System.out.println( team.get( "Dragon" ) );
      System.out.println( team.get( "Wizard" ) );
   }

}

class RpgPerson
{

   private int hits;
   private int strength;
   private int magic;

   public RpgPerson( int hits, int strength, int magic )
   {
      this.hits = hits;
      this.strength = strength;
      this.magic = magic;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return "RpgPerson{" + "hits=" + hits + ", strength=" +
              strength + ", magic=" + magic + '}';
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with maps but is it possible to change the values inside?
Example if Sgt. Mayhem hits the dragon then the dragons hits will change to 'Dragon.(1)=Dragon(1)-Sgt. Mayhem(2)'.

Comment: Yes, you can change objects even if they are inside the map.  This is OK for values (value = second argument to `put()`), but not for keys.  If you change a map key, you'll lose the key.  Here, String is immutable so you can't accidentally change one.

Comment: Thanks, another question! How do I do if I want to use the HashMap from another class. Let's say I have a new class.
`class Test {
public void Xxx {
System.out.print( RpgPerson.team.get("Dragon"));
return }}`
This does not work but is there a way to get or change values from the HashMap from another class of function?

Comment: I think you should ask that as another question.

Comment: Okey, I've done that now. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944546/how-do-i-use-a-hashmap-from-another-class-or-function)

Answer (score 1):

Alright. So your problem is that, depending on the square clicked on, you want to output the respective date. Now, to solve your immediate problem, what you need to do is very basic (and ugly).

**Introduce some conditional Logic**

So you need to introduce another if, that is dependent on what the value of `name` is. If `name` is `"Hero"`, then pass one array.

```
if(name.equals("Hero")) {
    Stats.name(Stats.Hero)
}
```

If it is equal to `Hero` it will output the statistics for the Hero..

**The Problem here**

This isn't nice, but it's also a little bit pointless. If each square has a respective name, then why can't you take a different approach?

**Create your own Object**

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int health;
    // etc...
}
```

And create a `Cell` object..

```
public class Cell {
    private Person person;

    public Cell(Person person)
    {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Person getPerson() { return this.person; }
}
```

Now, your `CHESS.Board` can be a multidimensional array of type `Cell`. You can get the correct `Cell`, exactly how you are doing now, and you can access the `Person` object associated with that cell. What this approach does is, it removes the conditional logic. You can just grab the `Person` from the cell!

```
Cell cell = (CHESS.Board[e.getY() / squareSize][e.getX() / squareSize]);
Person person = cell.getPerson();
```

Now, you can also add a simple method to the `Person` class to print out its stats.

```
public void printStats() {
    System.out.println("My name is " + this.name + " and my health is " + this.health);
}
```

then you can call `person.printStats()`. This is much cleaner, less conditional logic and it follows the Java approach much more closely. The solution is more scalable and you're not having to work out what `Hero[3]` means. (And neither is the next person who works on your code).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Strings to identify objects in your program. Strings are evil.

Just put the array (`Hero` or `Villain`) in `CHESS.board` squares directly). you will need to change the type of your board to `int` array also (so it will be an array of array of int arrays).

You should rename your variables to begin with lower case letters, as is the Java convention.

If you have to map Strings to objects, you can use a `Map`.